# Matlab exp produces unexpected result

Tags: arrays, matlab, exp

As a Matlab-noob i've been experimenting a bit with the exp-function.
What I found was that putting:

```
a = 1.1
b = 5
test = exp (a+b)
```

produced the desired (correct) answer. (test = 445.8578)

However: replacing a with a matrix gave completely the wrong result. so

```
a = [1.1 1.3 2.5 4.3]
b = 5
test = exp(a+b)
```

produced a wrong result (test =   1.0e+04 *

0.0446    0.0545    0.1808    1.0938)

I'm probably overlooking something, but I don't know where I'm going wrong. 
Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me. Should have seen that myself. The shortG-format is a new one for me. Will definitely be using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It produces the correct result:

```
a = [1.1 1.3 2.5 4.3];
b = 5;
c = a + b

c = 
  6.1    6.3    7.5    9.3
```

Now lets calculate the exponential function of each of those values (rounded a bit):

```
exp(6.1) =    445.86
exp(6.3) =    544.6
exp(7.5) =  1'808.0
exp(9.3) = 10'938
```

You get the same results by

```
exp(c)

ans = 
    1.0e+04 *
     0.0446    0.0545    0.1808    1.0938
```

which means you have to multiply each printed element with `1.0e+04 = 10'000`, which is the correct result.

This is the standard output format of MATLAB and it allows to quickly see how large the different values are. There are several different formats (see the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) for more detailed information). Interesting might be `shortG`:

```
format shortG
exp(c)
ans =
    445.86       544.57         1808        10938
```

Which is exactly what you expected. As you see: It's just the output format.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving the right answer, it's just presenting it in exponential format: `1.0e+04 * 0.0446` is the same as `445.8578`.

You could try evaluating `test(1)` to verify that.